# Value of type '1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'String'

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I've been coding a Film Search thing for School, and I've came across this problem and I'm not sure how to solve it.

```
While Not FilmSearcher.EndOfData         'loop until end of file
    currentRow = FilmSearcher.ReadFields()   'read in the fields of each line
    For j = 0 To 3
        Films(i, j) = currentRow(j)      'put the fields into film array
    Next

    i = i + 1
End While
```

currentRow = FilmSearcher.ReadFields() is the part that isn't working

Comment: Show the filmsearch.readfields code.

Answer (score 6):

If the error message is in your title, then I bet you have declared the currentRow as

```
Dim currentRow As String
```

instead you need to declare it as a 1-dimensional array

```
Dim currentRow() as String
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `currentRow` variable is not declared correctly. Instead of this:

```
Dim currentRow As String
```

You need one of these:

```
Dim currentRow() As String
Dim currentRow As String()
```

Which one you choose is a matter of preference. They mean the same thing. You can also avoid the variable entirely:

```
While Not FilmSearcher.EndOfData        
    'read in the fields of each line and put into film array
    Films(i) = FilmSearcher.ReadFields()          
    i = i + 1
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had declared my method incorrectly to return an array:

```
Function GetById(ByVal id As Integer) As String
```

and the syntax should be:

```
Function GetById(ByVal id As Integer) As String()
```

whereas I can return an array of strings:

```
Dim arrayOfStrings() As String
arrayOfStrings = {"John", "Josh", "Jason", "Jill", "Kunta Kinte"}
Return arrayOfStrings
```